# BigQuery Output the number of rows in a given query

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like like to count the different types of an output after a query is run on BigQuery (legacy SQL). For example I have a table that has different types of html status codes. It looks like this when I run this query:

`SELECT status, COUNT(status)
FROM [app_logs]
WHERE status >='300' AND DATE(CAST(start_time AS DATE)) >= '2017-11-23' AND DATE(CAST(end_time AS DATE)) <= '2017-12-22'
GROUP BY status`

Output:

`Row    status  f0_

 1       404    11

 2       403    27

 3       302    8

 4       500    11`

I would like the final output of the query to just count how many different status types (404, 403, 302, 500) there are, so in this example the final output would be:

`f0_
  4`

Is there a way to do this with just one query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(status)
FROM [app_logs]
WHERE status >='300' 
AND DATE(CAST(start_time AS DATE)) >= '2017-11-23' 
AND DATE(CAST(end_time AS DATE)) <= '2017-12-22'
```

Comment: Just did. Had to wait for the timeout. Thanks again!